# Optimizing array iteration with nested Where (LINQ) clauses

Tags: c#, .net, performance, linq, linq-to-objects

I am creating a (C#) tool that has a search functionality. The search is kind of similar to a "go to anywhere" search (like ReSharper has or VS2013).

The search context is a string array that contains all items up front:

```
private string[] context; // contains thousands of elements
```

Searching is incremental and occurs with every new input (character) the user provides.

I have implemented the search using the LINQ Where extension method:

```
// User searched for "c"
var input = "c";
var results = context.Where(s => s.Contains(input));
```

When the user searches for "ca", I attempted to use the previous results as the search context, however this causes (i think?) a nested Where iteration, and does not run very well. Think of something like this code:

```
// Cache these results.
var results = var results = context.Where(s => s.Contains(input));

// Next search uses the previous search results
var newResults = results.Where(s => s.Contains(input));
```

Is there any way to optimize this scenario?

Converting the IEnumerable into an array with every search causes high memory allocations and runs poorly.

Comment: You could materialize the intermediate result with `ToList`. But is that really more efficient than using `context` everytime?

Comment: is ToList better than ToArray ?

Comment: You are not using `ToArray` do you? `ToList` can be more efficient if the list is large since the doubling algorithm just needs to find a size that is greater or equal the item-count whereas an array must have the correct size. But that was not my point.

Comment: This sounds like the perfect use case for [Rx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577611), I've seen exactly this case in multiple examples and tutorials, if i find one i'll post it or write a answer around it.

Comment: Consider using smart string search algorithms, as your input string grows and number of patterns increases, performance may drop significantly.
For example, [Aho-Corasick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) or 
[Rabin-Karp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm)

Comment: There is always a tendency to over-optimize. Thousands of elements sounds like a relatively small number as far as the computer is concerned. Are you seeing performance issues? Might you publish a specification for what you would like to see (e.g. result in 20 milliseconds)?

Comment: @theMayer yes, the reason i have to optimize is the search is not responsive.

Answer (score 1):

Presenting the user with thousands of search results is pretty useless. You should add a "top" (`Take` in linq) statement to your query before presenting the result to the user.

```
var results = context.Where(s => s.Contains(input)).Take(100);
```

And if you want to present the next 100 results to the user:

```
var results = context.Where(s => s.Contains(input)).Skip(100).Take(100);
```

Also just use the original array for all the searches, no nested `Where` as it has no benefits unless you materialize the query.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to add that I obviously do not display thousands of results. I only take a small amount (e.g: 10).

Comment: The issue is that after a few search the query is something similar to: context.Where(s => s.Contains(input1)).Where(s => s.Contains(input2)) and so on...

Comment: How large are the strings in the array? How long does the initial search with for example one character using `.Take(100)` take?

Comment: The strings are full paths to files. Can get pretty long, but average search is around few chars long. The initial search (1 char) is very fast and responsive.

Comment: I don't see why any following search would be slower.

Comment: It can be slower if he does what he says he does (uses the result of the first where as the context for the second)

Comment: Just use the original array for all the searches. Searching a string array in memory with a couple of thousand elements in the size of file paths should be very very quick.

Answer (score 1):

I got a couple of useful points to add, too many for a comment.

First off, i agree with the other comments that you should start with `.take(100)`, decrease the load time. Even better, add one result at the time:

```
var results = context.Where(s => s.Contains(input));
var resultEnumerator = result.GetEnumerator()
```

Loop over the resultEnumerator to display results one at the time, stop when the screen is full or a new search is initiated.

Second, throttle your input. If the user writes `Hello`, you do not want to shoot off 5 searches for `H`, `He`, `Hel`, `Hell` and `Hello`, you want to search for just `Hello`. When the user later add `world`, it could be worthwhile to take your old result and add `Hello world` to the where clause.

```
results = results.Where(s => s.Contains(input));
resultEnumerator = result.GetEnumerator()
```

And of course, cancel the current in progress result when the user adds new text.

Using [Rx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577611), the throttle part is easy, you would get something like this:

```
var result = context.AsEnumerable();
var oldStr = "";
var resultEnumerator = result.GetEnumerator();
Observable.FromEventPattern(h => txt.TextChanged += h, h => txt.TextChanged -= h)
         .Select(s => txt.Text)
         .DistinctUntilChanged().Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300))
         .Subscribe(s =>
         {
             if (s.Contains(oldStr))
                 result = result.Where(t => t.Contains(s));
             else
                 result = context.Where(t => t.Contains(s));
             resultEnumerator = result.GetEnumerator();
             oldStr = s;
             // and probably start iterating resultEnumerator again,
             // but perhaps not on this thread.
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

If allocs are your concern and you don't want to write a trie implementation or use third party code, you should get away with partitioning your context array successively to clump matching entries together in the front. Not very LINQ-ish, but fast and has zero memory cost.

The partitioning extension method, based on C++'s [std::partition](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/partition/)

```
/// <summary>
/// All elements for which predicate is true are moved to the front of the array.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="start">Index to start with</param>
/// <param name="end">Index to end with</param>
/// <param name="predicate"></param>
/// <returns>Index of the first element for which predicate returns false</returns>
static int Partition<T>(this T[] array, int start, int end, Predicate<T> predicate)
{
    while (start != end)
    {
        // move start to the first not-matching element
        while ( predicate(array[start]) )
        {
            if ( ++start == end )
            {
                return start;
            }
        }

        // move end to the last matching element
        do
        {
            if (--end == start)
            {
                return start;
            }
        }
        while (!predicate(array[end]));

        // swap the two
        var temp = array[start];
        array[start] = array[end];
        array[end] = temp;

        ++start;
    }
    return start;
}
```

So now you need to store the last partition index, which should be initialised with `context` length:

```
private int resultsCount = context.Length;
```

Then for each change in input that's incremental you can run:

```
resultsCount = context.Partition(0, resultsCount, s => s.Contains(input));
```

Each time this will only do the checks for elements that haven't been filtered out previously, which is exactly what you are after.

For each non-incremental change you'll need to reset `resultsCount` to the original value.

You can expose results in a convenient, debugger and LINQ friendly way:

```
public IEnumerable<string> Matches
{
    get { return context.Take(resultsCount); }
}
```